# make status bar above the collapsed toolbar imageview

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-statusbar

https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterializeYourApp

I basically followed the code in the link above but I still couldn't make the status bar above the collapsed toolbar imageview.

One thing I found would work is to put `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` in the style. But that would make the toolbar and status bar overlap.

[CollapsedToolbarImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqvD7.png)   [ExpandedToolbarImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZTNu.png)

Basically I want the status bar in the first image to be like the second. And I guess the statusbar is already translucent. This is partially what I put in the style.

`<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>`

Another problem is that I set the collapsed title text programmatically but it is also not showing up.

I also have tried putting around some fitSystemWindow="true" but it still doesn't work. Below is the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/up_app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/up_ctoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="center"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/title_activity_scrolling"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="true"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/up_toolbar">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_background"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/up_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/up_back"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back_white" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/up_search"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_white" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/user_profile_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: try and add `<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>` to your app theme.

Comment: @KaranMer sadly doesn't work.

Comment: do you want to set only status bar transparent or both toolbar and statusbar?

Comment: I think the status is already transparent but it's just not above the imageview.

Comment: can you set `fitsSystemWindows="false"` in your parent coordinator layout and try.

Comment: @KaranMer This is one of the answers I saw on the stack overflow and tried. I wish this could help. This even makes the status bar not above the image view when the toolbar is expanded.

Answer (score 0):

You should add below code to your AppBarLayout block

```
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

It should help you fix the issue

Comment: Sadly it doesn't. By the way I set the title but it also not showing up do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

****UPDATE****
I'll just take yours and make it functional and paste below. I also use Material bars instead of widget, so if you don't have the material library you will need to add it to your gradle.

```
 implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
```

Now for the layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/up_app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/up_ctoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="center"
        app:titleEnabled="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/YourColor"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:scrimAnimationDuration="400"
        app:statusBarScrim="@color/transparent"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/up_toolbar">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_background"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/up_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/up_back"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back_white" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/up_search"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_white" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

STYLE:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

****OLD ANSWER****

I know it's a bit late, but if it helps anyone else.
add:

```
app:titleEnabled="false"
```

to your collapsing toolbar for the title issue.

For the toolbar floating above the imageView, set the layout_gravity of the imageView to bottom or it defaults to center. This will give you the bottom imageview beneath the toolbar you are looking for.

Optional:

Parallax is used to give a nice parallel scrolling effect animation to the imageview into the toolbar.

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarCollapsingImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
```

Comment: I just tried that. I simply changed `app:titleEnabled="true"` of `up_ctoolbar` to `app:titleEnabled="false"` and add `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to my `header`. And the status bar is only floating above the image when scrolling. When it's fully collapsed or fully uncollapsed, the status bar is still stacked above the `imageview`.

Comment: Hi @SeakyLuo I went ahead and just took your example and redid it for you. Give it a shot, but it should work just fine. The only thing I'm not sure of is your imageButtons inside the toolbar, I'm guessing that is your way of skipping the normal menu inflate flow, but if you see weird behavior, remove those first.